# How do I select only an image that's NOT inside a link when both are inside the same ID?

Tags: html, css

I have some code that I can't alter that's like this:

```
<div id="wombat">
    <a href=""><img src="a"></a>
    <img src="b">
</div>
```

I want to only target img b.  #wombat img {blah} is getting both of them.  I know that #wombat a img would target only img a, but is there a way to do just img b?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the sibling or the descendant operator, depending on what you want to achieve:

```
#wombat > img {
    /* any images that reside directly below #wombat, without any more levels in between */
}

a ~ img {
    /* any image that follows as a sibling to an anchor */
}

a + img {
    /* an image that follows as direct sibling to an anchor */
}
```

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors (`>`)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors (`~`)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors (`+`)

Answer (score 2):

Use the direct descendant combinator `>` to target the image that is directly inside the div:

```
#wombat > img { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the img is always a child of the div, then `#wombat>img`
If u do not know how deep it is inside the div, but it should never be under `a`, You will need to use JS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#wombat img[src="a"].
```

I think this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes afcource, this is so simple you can do it like this:

```
$("#wombat").children("img[src=b]")
```

Comment: Here is asked for html and css, not jQuery

Comment: Nonetheless this would work in CSS too: `#wombat img[src="b"]`, but I never would use an image path as a selector; (what happens if the images changes?); BTW @VivekGarg For such simple tasks, even if you use JS, there is no need to incorporate jQuery or some other library as this could be done with plain JS: `document.querySelectorAll( '#wombat img[src="b"]' );`, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll

Comment: I Just served his purpose for the given scenario.